# How to order by where in fields in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I did some calculate in a view table for products in MYSQL, so I list these id for product reference id.

```
$referenceIds = viewTable::orderBy('score', 'DESC')->lists('product_id');
```

And I want to get the product from those reference id.

```
$products = Product::whereIn('id', $rederenceIds);
```

The product content is correct, but the order is wrong, how to load product order by reference id, I know I can do it in MySQL by using `ORDER BY FIELD(id,' . $fields . ')`, but I want to find out Laravel way, and hope not use `ORDER BY FIELD` command because it seems waste to much database efficiency.

Comment: As an end result, are you trying to order the products or the referenceIds?

Comment: `orderBy(DB::raw('FIELD(id, ' . implode(',', $productStarScoreIds) . ')'), 'ASC')`, this is the solution, but I want to find out Laravel solution if possible.

Answer (score 13):

You will have to inject some raw sql, but it's not a nightmare:

```
$referenceIds = viewTable::orderBy('score', 'DESC')->lists('product_id');
$referenceIdsStr = implode(',', $referenceIds);
$products = Product::whereIn('id', $rederenceIds)->orderByRaw(DB::raw("FIELD(product_id, $referenceIdsStr)"))->get()->all();
```

Comment: If you are already using `orderByRaw`, so no need to use `DB :: raw`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand this entirely, but if you want the products ordered, you should use

```
$referenceIds = viewTable::lists('product_id');

$ordered_products = Product::whereIn('id', $rederenceIds)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
```

Comment: I want to order by reference product id, not the result product id.

Answer (score -1):

If the key is primay key (I think in this question it is ...), you can try this:

```
$products = Product::whereIn('id', $rederenceIds)->get();
$products = array_replace(array_flip($rederenceIds), $products->getDictionary());
```

The result is **Array**, not **Collection**.

I don't know whether it has an efficiency problem, but order by field has other problems. For example, order by field is not supported by sqlite so it doesn't work in testing with in-memory database.