# How to keep order of collected database row the same as array passed to where clause

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel, laravel-4

I am working on a project using Laravel 4.2 and I have a line that retrieves some rows from a table called Gifts

```
$theGifts = Gift::whereIn('id', $giftImages)->get();
```

This variable `$giftImages` is an array and values are ordered like this

```
Array 
(
    [0] => 5
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
)
```

When I output this one however `$theGifts` the retrieved results are not in the same order as the array of ids is and I need it to be in the same order..

**How can I insure that the order is the same?** I am using the data from the object in the controller, not the view by the way.

The printout of the `Gift::all()` looks like this (in case someone needs to compare)..

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => Gift Object
                (
                    [table:protected] => gifts
                    [connection:protected] => 
                    [primaryKey:protected] => id
                    [perPage:protected] => 15
                    [incrementing] => 1
                    [timestamps] => 1
                    [attributes:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [name] => Banana
                            [image] => bananas-icon.png
                            [value] => 10
                        )

                    [original:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [name] => Banana
                            [image] => bananas-icon.png
                            [value] => 10
                        )

                    [relations:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [hidden:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [visible:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [appends:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [fillable:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [guarded:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => *
                        )

                    [dates:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [touches:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [observables:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [with:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [morphClass:protected] => 
                    [exists] => 1
                )

            [1] => Gift Object
                (
                    [table:protected] => gifts
                    [connection:protected] => 
                    [primaryKey:protected] => id
                    [perPage:protected] => 15
                    [incrementing] => 1
                    [timestamps] => 1
                    [attributes:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [name] => Cherry Cake
                            [image] => Cherry-Cake-icon.png
                            [value] => 15
                        )

                    [original:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [name] => Cherry Cake
                            [image] => Cherry-Cake-icon.png
                            [value] => 15
                        )

                    [relations:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [hidden:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [visible:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [appends:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [fillable:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [guarded:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => *
                        )

                    [dates:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [touches:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [observables:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [with:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [morphClass:protected] => 
                    [exists] => 1
                )

            [2] => Gift Object
                (
                    [table:protected] => gifts
                    [connection:protected] => 
                    [primaryKey:protected] => id
                    [perPage:protected] => 15
                    [incrementing] => 1
                    [timestamps] => 1
                    [attributes:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 4
                            [name] => Coconut
                            [image] => coconut-icon.png
                            [value] => 5
                        )

                    [original:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 4
                            [name] => Coconut
                            [image] => coconut-icon.png
                            [value] => 5
                        )

                    [relations:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [hidden:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [visible:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [appends:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [fillable:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [guarded:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => *
                        )

                    [dates:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [touches:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [observables:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [with:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [morphClass:protected] => 
                    [exists] => 1
                )

            [3] => Gift Object
                (
                    [table:protected] => gifts
                    [connection:protected] => 
                    [primaryKey:protected] => id
                    [perPage:protected] => 15
                    [incrementing] => 1
                    [timestamps] => 1
                    [attributes:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 5
                            [name] => Lemon
                            [image] => lemon-icon.png
                            [value] => 3
                        )

                    [original:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 5
                            [name] => Lemon
                            [image] => lemon-icon.png
                            [value] => 3
                        )

                    [relations:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [hidden:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [visible:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [appends:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [fillable:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [guarded:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => *
                        )

                    [dates:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [touches:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [observables:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [with:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [morphClass:protected] => 
                    [exists] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this will do it for you:

```
Gift::whereIn('id', $giftImages)
    ->orderBy(DB::raw('FIELD(id, ' . implode(',', $giftImages) . ')'), 'ASC')
    ->get();
```

Taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19560590/how-to-order-by-where-in-fields-in-laravel). You have to use `DB::raw()` since Laravel doesn't provide a native way to do this. Untested...